# iAd banner not loading when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I have an iAd banner located at the bottom of my app. The banner displays fine on test devices and the delegate methods appear to be called appropriately.

My issue is.  When I tap the "*You're Connected To iAd*" banner, nothing is loaded. Normally, I would expect to see a another full screen iAd view pop up. I see the banner darken when I tap it and then it returns to normal when I remove my finger.

`bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool)` does fire and `willLeave` is == false.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {
var bannerView: ADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.bannerView = ADBannerView()
    self.bannerView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, view.frame.height-50, view.frame.width, 50)
    self.bannerView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this - `ADBannerViewDelegate`

create variable - `var adBanner = ADBannerView()`

In viewDidLoad()

```
        adBanner = iADManager.sharedInstance
        adBanner.delegate = self
        if DeviceType.IS_IPAD {
            adBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.width, 65);
        }
        else {
            adBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.width, 50);
        }
```

Delegate Methods **[if fetched successfully ad then this will add subviews otherwise remove from view]**

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.view.addSubview(banner)
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        banner.removeFromSuperview()
    }

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Below is My shareInstance class. This will more helpful for memory management and loading ads.

```
class iADManager{

    class var sharedInstance: ADBannerView {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: ADBannerView? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.Banner)
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bob this is helpful to you? or any queries??

Comment: No luck, same result. bannerViewDidLoadAd fires but the full screen AD is never displayed. In this case the iAd test ad. I writing to the console so I know the methods are called and the tap is recognized.

Comment: plz double check that you have not added any uiview on the screen that hides the full screen iad.? by the way on tapping banner this is default behaviour that this present a full screen iad. and after closing this there is a normal view controller and banner is exist.

Comment: The was that I implemented  `func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        NSLog("Banner Leaving... \(willLeave)")
        return willLeave
    }`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I implemented...

```
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {NSLog("Banner Leaving... \(willLeave)")
    return willLeave
}
```

`willLeave` was set to `false` so I either had to return `true` or not implement the method. I chose to just return `true`

Comment: ohk @Bob, thanks, but do you really need above method? that is return willLeave

Comment: I really don't need the method so I decided to remove it. Thanks for your help. I will use your iAdManger class going forward